# Docker Run CodeIgniter projects shows Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found

Tags: php, docker, codeigniter

I am trying to run a CodeIgniter project in Docker but it's shown in the logs that there's no index.php/index.html found.

I have phpMyadmin running on `localhost:8082` but the CodeIgniter project that is supposed to run on `localhost:8080` is not working.

My folder structure is

```
var/www/html/
           application
           db-data
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  codeigniter:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sortdb
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - database
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testpassword
```

And my Dockerfile is

```
# Use an official PHP image as the base image
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Enable mod_rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Grant permissions to the Apache user
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# Copy your CodeIgniter application files into the container
COPY . .

# Expose the Apache web server port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the Apache server
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Comment: Is there an index.php file in the /app directory? Normally it should be in /public.

Comment: @CodeSpirit what should i change to that the directory is point in /public?

Comment: @Tristan, Since there is a mapping of the local `app` directory to `/var/www/html`, there should be an index file (e.g. `index.php`) in the `app`. This part is not apparent from your question. Please add the necessary details to the description of the project structure (including the `index.php`).

Comment: Normally you should have a `public` directory in you project besides your `app` directory which contains your index.php.  You have to mount your whole project directory as volume and then set apaches document root to `/var/www/html/public`